# How to test file manipulation

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, file, testing

I hear that accessing to database is wrong in testing.

But what about file manipulation? Things like, `cp`, `mv`, `rm` and `touch` methods in FileUtils.

If I write a test and actually run the commands (moving files, renaming files, making directories and so on), I can test them. But I need to "undo" every command I ran before running a test again. So I decided to write all the code to "undo", but it seems a waste of time because I don't really need to "undo".

I really want to see how others do. How would you test, for example, when you generate a lot of static files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case accessing the files is totally legit, if you are writing file manipulation code it should be tested on files. The one thing you have to be careful about is that a failed test means that you code is wrong and not that somebody deleted a file that is needed for the test or something like that. I would put the directory and the files you need for the tests in a separate folder that is only used for the test. Then in the build up of the test copy the whole folder to a temporary place do all the testing and then after the test delete the temporary files. In that way each test has a clean copy of the files that are saved for the test.

Answer (score 3):

"Pure" unit testing shall [not access "expensive" resources](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923) such as filesystem, DB ...

Now you may want to run those "integration" tests (or whatever you call them) at the same time as your unit-tests, and use the same framework it's convenient.

You can have a set of files for unit testing that you copy into temporary location as suggested in Janusz' answer, or generate them in your unit tests, or you can use a [mock of the FileUtils](http://mockfs.rubyforge.org/) instead of the real FileUtils when unit testing.

Comment: I didn't know about the mock library. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Accessing resources like the database, file system, smtp server, etc. are bad ideas for *unit testing*. At some point obviously you have to do have to try it out with real files, that's a different kind of test, an integration test. Integration tests are more painful, you do have to take care to make sure your test is starting from a well-defined state, also they will run slower since you're accessing the real file system. On the other hand you shouldn't have to run them as frequently as you would with unit tests.

For unit tests you should be able to take advantage of duck typing to create objects that react to the same methods that the file objects you're working with have. Plus there's nothing to undo with this approach, and the tests will run a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a database is not "wrong in testing". How else will you test the integration of your code with the database?

The key to repeatable testing is a consistent environment. So long as you start from the same file system or database contents for your tests, you should are not wrong.  This is usually handled via a cleanup process at the start of the test suite.

Answer (score 1):

If your operating system supports RAM-based filesystems, you could go with one of these. This has even the advantage that an occasional `` `unix command` `` in your code keeps working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a directory inside your test package named "test_*". Then, the files that you change will be put on this directory (for example: if you create a directory, you will create the directory inside the test directory). At the end of the test you could delete this directory (with only one command). This is the unique UNDO operation that you will execute.

You will put all files that you need to the test on your test directory inside the test package.